# Regular expression that can describe a string

Tags: python, regex

I have an alphabet `{A, B, C}` and a (large) number of words over this alphabet:
`AAABBCABBCCCCAA, ABBBCCC, BBBBCACAC, ...` (different lengths, different combinations)

I'm looking for a set of regular expressions (the smaller the better) that can describe these words. I prefer compact (`(BC)+` over `BCBC`). It's not homework.

1. What's a good way to do this?
2. Is there a Python package that already does this?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626800/finding-regular-expressions-for-languages-otherwise-described) to be related.

**Update**: I might have rushed when saying I prefer `(BC)+` over `BCBC`. I prefer to have as few expressions as possible (in the worst case there is one regex per string), so preference for one of `A+`, `AA`, or `AA+` to describe `AA` (for example) should depend on what patterns other strings show.

Comment: Is your goal to acquire a set of regular expression which matches the words specifically? (Is there an issue with simply using something like `[A-C]+`?)

Comment: Obviously you can make a `NFA` to match all these strings, (convert that to `DFA`) minimize it and turn it into a Regex, so it will match your strings set.

Comment: @Vulcan Yes, I want to match the words specifically. I think the DFA+NFA would do it.

Comment: @JBernardo I was not aware of the DFA/NFA approach. I thought about replacing sequences of `A`'s by `A+` but realised it wouldn't suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem, you have an alphabet, and a list of string on that alphabet and you want to build a pattern that match exactly those strings.

You can probably construct a [deterministic finite automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automata) for each of the string, construct from that a [non-deterministic finite automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) that is the combination of all of those [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automata). Then simplify the [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automata) to a [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton). Then just transform the NFA to a pattern.

This will even work if instead of strings you have already pattern. However, there is no guarantee that you'll get the smallest possible pattern.

I don't know of any library to manipulate [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automata) or [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways of processing strings with those words, but only the first requires a regular expression:

```py
strings =['AAABBCABBCCCCAA', 'ABBBCCC', 'BBBBCACAC']

import re
for string in strings:
    matches = re.findall(r'([A-C]+)', string)
    if matches:
        print matches[0]
```

Output:

```
AAABBCABBCCCCAA
ABBBCCC
BBBBCACAC
```

Alternatively you might be able to use something like this, depending on what you intended to do with the regex for words:

```py
from itertools import groupby
results = [(string, [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(string)]) for string in strings]
print
for result in results:
    print '{}: {}'.format(*result)
```

Output:

```
AAABBCABBCCCCAA: ['AAA', 'BB', 'C', 'A', 'BB', 'CCCC', 'AA']
ABBBCCC: ['A', 'BBB', 'CCC']
BBBBCACAC: ['BBBB', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C']
```